# How to convert query with decode to a query in Hibernate (HQL)?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

I want to convert the following query in Oracle to a Hibernate HQL query

```
select 
      SYSTEM, 
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'HIGH',YAXIS,0)) H,
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'MEDIUM',YAXIS,0)) M, 
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'LOW',YAXIS,0)) L
      from HOME 
      where
          DATA_KEY=5 
      GROUP BY SYSTEM
```

I want use `createQuery()` to make it database independent and do not want to use Native SQL

How do I write the above query in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use case instead of decode.

Using case your query will be converted from

```
select 
      SYSTEM, 
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'HIGH',YAXIS,0)) H,
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'MEDIUM',YAXIS,0)) M, 
      sum(decode(trim(XAXIS),'LOW',YAXIS,0)) L
      from HOME 
      where
          DATA_KEY=5 
  GROUP BY SYSTEM
```

to

```
select 
      SYSTEM, 
      sum(case when trim(XAXIS) = 'HIGH' then YAXIS else 0 end) H,
      sum(case when trim(XAXIS) = 'MEDIUM' then YAXIS else 0 end) M, 
      sum(case when trim(XAXIS) = 'LOW' then YAXIS else 0 end) L
      from HOME 
      where
          DATA_KEY=5 
      GROUP BY SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you? a HQL query is stringbased, so is CreateSqlQuery. if you use `Session.CreateSqlQuery()` you do not need to know anything about the HQL syntaxt.

Comment: I want use createQuery() to make it database independent

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an entity named `Home`. `decode` function is not supported in HQL, but you can create a property with a formula like this:

```
<property name="prop1" type="Double" formula="decode(trim(XAXIS),'HIGH',YAXIS,0)" />
<property name="prop2" type="Double" formula="decode(trim(XAXIS),'MEDIUM',YAXIS,0)" />
<property name="prop3" type="Double" formula="decode(trim(XAXIS),'LOW',YAXIS,0)" />
```

Then you can write your HQL query:

```
select 
    h.SYSTEM, 
    sum(h.prop1) H,
    sum(h.prop2) M, 
    sum(h.prop3) L
from HOME h
where h.DATA_KEY=5 
GROUP BY h.SYSTEM
```

Comment: Where do I add this <property name="prop1" type="Double" formula="decode(trim(XAXIS),'HIGH',YAXIS,0)" />
tag , I'm at present using annotations

Comment: Do I need 2 add 2 more attributes prop1 and prop2 to my entity class Home??

Comment: Yes, just add them into `HOME.hbm.xml`. Beware that Java classes and properties are case sensitive in HQL.

Comment: Could you tell me hoe to do it with annotations?

Comment: `@Formula("decode(trim(XAXIS),'HIGH',YAXIS,0)")
private Double prop1;`